# Transaction log file for FAST Search

Tags: sql-server, database, fast-search

I have a FAST database that has a transaction log file that is growing at an unusually high rate, possibly after applying the FAST SP2 update.  It ends up taking up the whole volume within a few days.  The database is in Simple Recovery mode, so I thought that it wouldn't have a transaction log file but it is there.  I get an error trying to delete it because it is in use.  I can shrink the log file every few days but I'd rather just remove it if it's safe to the integrity of the database.  What would be the best way handle this?